# Why PHP include method do not work on these codes?

Tags: php, mysql, php-8, php-8.1

I didn't understand it why happens. When I try to get other errors they are including to the page so I can see the error but 404.php couldn't included.

```
<?php
include('views/nav.php');
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = preg_replace('#[\s]+#',' ',htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    if ( is_numeric($id) ) { 
        try{
            $query->execute();
            $blogs = $query->fetchAll();
            if( empty($blogs) ) {
                include('error_pages/404.php'); # DOESN'T WORK
            } else {
                foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
                    include('views/article.php');
                }
            }
            // Close connection.
            $conn = null; 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            include('error_pages/500.php'); # THIS ONE IS WORKS.
            // echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        include('error_pages/400.php'); # THIS ONE IS WORKS.
    }
} else {
    include('views/blog.php');
}
include('views/footer.php');
?>
```

I tested these steps;

1. I broke the query so I get 500 error. That include is working.
2. I drop a ' to the dynamic link, like [www.domain.com/blog.php?id='](http://www.domain.com/blog.php?id=%27) so I get 400 error. That include is working too.
3. But when I drop an another id for example '?id=2' (there is no 2 id row on database) it is not giving 404 so that include is not working. I need help.

Comment: What is it doing instead of giving the 404?

Comment: It gives nothing.

Comment: You might want to try a `var_dump($blogs)` before your if/else to see what it contains

Comment: Looks like there's some code missing. Where does `$query` come from? Does it come from `nav.php`? You're also not using `$id` anywhere (and why are you using `preg_replace()` and `htmlspecialchars()`?) And what does your `404.php` actually contain? Have you checked the web servers error log?

Comment: Consider using fixed paths to see if everything works in this scenario, if so the problem you are encountering is that the file you are trying to access is not in the directory where php is looking for

Comment: @aynber I added a "echo 'bla';" after if( empty($blogs) ) statement. It works but include() in the under line of echo, it not works. This kinda weird.

Comment: @Herossandro I am gonna restart my computer :D.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I deleted $query in these codes not come from nav.php. I didn't check logs I will look them.

Comment: And what does `404.php` contain?

Comment: "404.php couldn't included" - what does that mean? What happens instead? Also, is this a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: Do you need `include` instead of `require`?

Comment: Shouldn't you get rid of whitespace instead of turning it into a single blank?

Comment: Is there an issue with the connection code?  What is $query set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solve. I was created a directory on web project it was /error_pages/ and it's owner was me and the group of it was www-data (I'm working on NGINX). I wanted to go and check for permissions. When I type the '**ls -l**' it returned the '**owner:owner**' value. You need to to that for NGINX;

1. Go to parent of your web project. (www for mine; (/var/www/domain.com))
2. In the www folder execute this command: **sudo chown -R YOUR_USER:www-data YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER**

Execute the following command on terminal. This command will set group of your web project as www-data.

Problem solved ^-^